# Is it possible to get the "Carta Blu" in Italy with my 3-year Associate's Degree Diploma (Laurea Breve)?

Tags: blue-card, italy

I am in the process to work in Italy. The prerequisite for working there is to obtain a Work Visa. The Work Visa is called "Carta Blu EU" (Blue Card).
The Italian Authority send to me and my employer **[a link](https://www2.immigrazione.regione.toscana.it/?q=procedimentiamministrativi&procedimento=1878&pa_prov=FI)** with the prerequisites to get the Blue Card and one of them is:

> declaration of value issued by the Italian diplomatic-consular
> representation in the country of residence of the worker, relating to
> higher education qualifications lasting ***at least three years***...

I'm from Brazil and I have a 3-year diploma as an Associate's Degree.
I already obtained the ***Declaration of Value*** from the Italian consular authority in Brazil, and this document informs me that my university graduation is "Laurea Breve".

Does anyone know if this level of education is sufficient to acquire the Blu Card?
All help is very welcome.

Observations: I had read that "*Laurea Triennale*" and "*Laura Breve*" are the same qualifications.